# How do we pop one stack completely into another stack

Tags: java, stack

I have this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < StackA.capacity(); i++) {
    StackB.push(StackA.get(i));
}
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
Array index out of range: 0
    at java.base/java.util.Vector.get
```

Can anybody help me identify my mistake?

Comment: You are using capacity as a condition for you loop. But just because a stack has a certain capacity doesn't mean that this is his actual size.

Comment: If you want to access by index, `Stack` aint the suitable data structure for you

Comment: As an aside you're not using `StackA` as a stack. You should `pop` from it until it's empty.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS so can I use i < StackA.size()?

Comment: @HariHaravelan its the assignment requirement

Comment: Unrelated: learn about java naming conventions. Fields/variable/method (parameter) names all go camelCase. Only class names go UpperCamelCase!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you're looking is how to add elements into `stackB` without removing the elements from `atackA`, then you could use an `Iterator` to traverse `stackA` and add its elements into `stackB`.

```
//Adding elements within stackB without consuming stackA
for (Iterator<Integer> it = stackA.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    stackB.push(it.next());
}
```

Otherwise, as it has been suggested in the comments, if consuming the elements within `stackA` is not a problem, you could simply iterate your first stack until it's empty and popping each element into `stackB` during every iteration.

```
//Adding elements within stackB by consuming stackA
while (!stackA.empty()) {
    stackB.push(stackA.pop());
}
```